# What is the size in bits of a file descriptor in an x64 system running Ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: c, linux, assembly, x86-64, file-descriptor

What is the size in bits of a file descriptor such as standard input and standard output, is it a 32-bit integer?

Comment: `CHAR_BIT * sizeof stdin` you may need to `#include <limits.h>`

Comment: The type of a file descriptor is `int` as you can tell by looking at the specifications for `open()` et al. File streams are different; the contain a file descriptor and other information, usually including a pointer to a buffer.  Note that `stdin` is a file stream. File descriptor 0 is the descriptor used for standard input.  Since `int` is normally at 32-but type, file descriptors are normally 32-but signed numbers. But negative values are invalid.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jonathan Leffler, that's exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @pmg: `stdin` has type `FILE *`, which is a stdio `FILE` pointer.  But the question title and tags are about POSIX file *descriptors*, like POSIX `open` returns, and which are used as arguments to real system calls, not stdio library functions.  So the question is ambiguous.

Comment: @PeterCordes: for POSIX *file descriptors* use `CHAR_BIT * sizeof 42`

Comment: @pmg: yes, exactly.  Or `CHAR_BIT * sizeof(STDOUT_FILENO)` [from `unistd.h`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/unistd.h.html) if you want to be fancy about it.  Although really, even on a system where file descriptors were `long`, `STDOUT_FILENO` could still be defined as a literal `1` macro, so that doesn't prove anything.  Perhaps best is `CHAR_BIT * sizeof(open("foo",1))` - yes that compiles https://godbolt.org/z/akNFa7 and depends on the return type of `open`, instead of assuming it's `int`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are talking about the actual file descriptors returned by (and used for) Linux syscalls, then take a look at the manpage for `open` etc. as @JonathanLeffler suggests.

For instance:

> ```
> int open(const char *pathname, int flags);
> ```
>
> The  return  value of `open()` is a file descriptor, a small, nonnegative integer that is used in subsequent system calls. [...] The file descriptor returned by a successful call will be the lowest-numbered file descriptor not currently open for the process.

Given that Unix-like systems are LP64, `int` and therefore the file descriptors are 32-bit wide.

However, note that the kernel will give you as small integers as possible *and* that you will typically reach a limit way before that (see [Limits on the number of file descriptors](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84227/limits-on-the-number-of-file-descriptors)) either due to the kernel global limit or the soft/hard limits.

This means that, if you *really* needed it, you could in theory use a smaller integer to store your file descriptors, e.g. an `int16_t` or an `int8_t` (assuming that your process does not use that many file descriptors at a time).

---

If, instead, you are referring to `stdin` etc., those are not file descriptors but file streams defined by the C standard.

They are macros which expand to expressions with pointer type (`FILE *`), and pointers in a typical 64-bit platform like x86_64 are 64-bit wide.

See 7.21p3 (Input/output `<stdio.h>`):

> ```
> stdin
> stdout
> stderr
> ```
>
> which are expressions of type ‘‘pointer to `FILE`’’ that point to the `FILE` objects associated, respectively, with the standard error, input, and output streams.

Comment: Those are file streams, not file descriptors.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You are completely right -- updated!

Comment: @tadman Of course, if your program is going to end up requiring more than 64K handles at a time, then you cannot do it.

Comment: @tadman Whoever is going to do something crazy like that (even using a `int8_t`!) is doing so due to some constraint (likely in the embedded field). I am not recommending doing it for general purpose applications. The point is to show how the integer set looks like.

Comment: @tadman "*your code has limits that will not necessarily be easy to detect if they're exceeded*" You are assuming the code does not check whether the file descriptor fits in the destination, so I don't agree.

Comment: @tadman "*If it's embedded it'll have at least megabytes of memory*" Not really. The CPU might be 64-bit and still have *kilo*bytes of available memory. Yes, nobody would be using a Linux kernel for that, but that is not the point.

Comment: @tadman Putting things in bold letters doesn't make you right. Storing descriptors in an `int8_t` or not has nothing to do with being "reckless". Anytime you have to do any serdes (e.g. in network protocols) you face the exact same problem. Concerning "*doubly don't suggest abusing types just to...*" I have *nowhere* suggested that, so please don't put words in others' mouths. You are misunderstanding the point of that paragraph in the answer: to show how the FD set of integers looks like in practice.

Comment: @tadman "*There's an entire class of bug in software caused by people thinking they'll be clever and save a few bytes here and there only to cost millions of dollars in damages later.*" The fact that you correlate "people thinking they'll be clever" and "millions of dollars in damages" shows you have never worked in any industry where safety is involved or where millions of dollars are at stake. There are standards on how to write and test code for those. Fearmongering in StackOverflow about "`int8_t` file descriptors" is not going to change how safe a given project is.

Comment: Note that not all UNIX systems are LP64.  For example, Unicos is ILP64 and IIRC Windows NT is LLP64.